# How to setup sonar for code

Tags: java, build, sonarqube

I have installed sonar server as a service on a wintel dev box at work. i have also installed the eclipse sonar plugin.

in the properties (windows -> prefeences -> sonar -> servers)  i have setpu my connection and it connects no issues. Now, when i go to assoicate a project with sonar (right click -> configure -> associate with sonar) i get a dialogue box asking me to select the sonar project. I dont have one yet as this is the first time it has run so how to do i set this part up correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+in+Eclipse), it is necessary to analyse your project first before being able to associate your project.